# openssl not fetching certification details

Tags: openssl, ssl-certificate

we were able to connect but not fetching certification details.

$ bash-3.2# echo | openssl s_client -host $h -port $p 2>/dev/null

CONNECTED(00000005)

$

Answer (score 0):

You just need to pipe it back to into openssl now and tell it what parts or the whole certificate, you want. An example would be to tag on `| openssl x509 -text -noout` to the end so you can see the entire certificate.

The kind of command you add on to the ends of your statement define what information is pulled to the output. Do you have a certain piece of information in mind that you want to get?